Identification of componenet labeled 2310 from a dyson vacuum cleaner (v8) motorhead, maybe a thermistor?


I'd appreciate any help in identifying this component.

labeled 2310, no other markings
when disconnected vacuum's secondary "turbo" mode no longer functions
uses a 4pin plastic connector but only 2 pins are in use

Thanks!

Can you take a photo of this element marked 2310?

I agree it's most likely a thermistor. The thermistor itself is probably off the shelf, but I doubt the casing an wire leads are. Can you measure it?

To amplify @Drew comment: check resistance at nominal room temperature (~23°C), then warmed to 37°C (body temperature) or even 50°C, with a hair dryer, confirmed with a thermometer.
